# C# how to compare the values of two Datatables with a tolerance

Tags: c#, datatables, compare

Im working on a Tool which reads in two Datatables.
Those Datatables have the same ID(ForeignKey) but different values. 
For example : 
Table 1

```
ID Length Height
1    2.5    2.4
2    3.4    1.9
3    1.1    2.2
```

Table 2

```
ID Length Height
1    2.5    2.0
2    3.2    1.7
3    1.0    2.2
```

How do i compare those tables with a tolerance ? So it recognices where the IDs are the same in the two datatables and for example a difference of 0.1 by Length and a difference of 0.2 by Height is ok?

The perfect solution would be a table that would look like

```
    ID Length Height
1    ok        ok
2    not ok    ok
3    not ok    not ok
```

Is there any way to do that ? 
Thanks in regards

Answer (score 0):

Here can use case when to compare two column

EX:

```
select case when (2=2) then 'ok' else 'not ok' end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the case statement like below

```
select t1.ID
    CASE WHEN ABS(t1.LENGTH-t2.LENGTH)<0.1 then 'ok' else 'not ok 'end,
    CASE WHEN ABS(t1.HEIGHT-t2.HEIGHT)<0.2 then 'ok' else 'not ok 'end
  from TABLE1 t1 join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: How can i apply a sql query on datatable in c#?

Answer (score 0):

```
select tbl1.Id,
CASE when ABS(tbl1.Length-tbl2.Length)<=0.1 then 'OK' else 'Not OK' END,
CASE when ABS(tbl1.Height-tbl2.Height)<=0.2 then 'OK' else 'Not OK' END 
from table1 tbl1 inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.Id=tbl2.Id
```

### Use LinQ in case you want to Compare two Datatables

```
Datatable dtNew = (from dt1 in datatble1.AsEnumerable()
                     join dt2 in datatable2.AsEnumerable()
                     on dt1[id].ToString() = dt2[id].ToString()
                    .where()
                    .Select()
                  ).CopyToDatatable()
```

Apply where condition accordingly.
or You can Have Reference from 
 (https://forgetcode.com/csharp/1508-comparing-two-datatables-and-returning-a-datatable-by-matching-one-or-more-columns-using-linq)

Comment: How can i apply a sql query on datatable in c#?

Comment: Please explain how your answer helps solve the question. Posting code only answers does not usually help answer the question.

Comment: Did it help you Solve your Problem